# Geoserver SLD default style for feature?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I'm new with GeoServer.

I'm trying to style a Geoserver layer. The features come from a PostGIS table.

The feature are all lines. I'd like to style them based on attributes (of the table). I can do that. I created rules that say "if myfield = value1 draw a red line, if myfield = value2 draw a blue line, ..." and so on.

I'd like to write a default style for the line: "if none of the above rules is true than draw the line yellow".

I didn't find in the Geoserver SLD documentation anything to accomplish that. Or my way of reasoning is different from that of SLD.

In the docs there's a UserStyle is Default property but I think it's not what I'm looking for.

I Googled too to no avail.

Any suggestion?

Comment: look at else rules

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I used ElseFilter (undocumented on geoserver docs):
<FeatureTypeStyle>
 <Rule>
  <Name>myname</Name>
   <ogc:Filter>
 ...
 <Rule>
  <Name>Default</Name>
  <ElseFilter />
  <LineSymbolizer>
 ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can try styling your data with QGIS.
But if you want to create a rule based sld or an sld with more options (fill opacity, rules, outline etc) I recommend you to use [uDig](http://udig.refractions.net/download/). With you uDig you can style your data with many options and then export slds that will work 99,9% when uploaded on geoserver.

More about sld editor and uDig [here](http://udig.refractions.net/files/docs/latest/user/getting_started/walkthrough1/ThemedData.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could try styling it the way you like in qGIS and then exporting the SLD and using it in GeoServer.

Check out this article and try it out since I find it much easier to use than styling in the SLD itself or through GeoServer's interface.

http://www.camptocamp.com/actualite/qgis-and-geoserver-creating-styles/